# how do I install mysql on ubuntu 19.0.4 with a specific root password

Tags: mysql

I am running ubuntu 19.0.4

I installed mysql according to information I found with google searching.

The install completed successfully. However, at no point during the install process was I ever asked for a root password. So I did more google searching and tried to find a way to specify/assign a password for the root user. None of the solutions worked (most of them failed with all kinds of file/permission errors).

Now I am going to delete mysql and install it again. This time I would like to be able to assign the root password during the install process. How can I accomplish this task ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried to just press enter when prompted to enter root password? It might be blank if not initialized yet.

Comment: Here's an article that you can refer for MySQL install including how to set root password: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/installing-mysql-server-on-ubuntu/

Comment: yes, i did try to just press ENTER when prompted for the root password. that did not work.

Comment: Also try: sudo mysql_secure_installation

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesnt always ask for a password during installation. Whether it does or not you should run "sudo mysql_secure_installation" after install to configure MySQL, at which point it should ask you for a root password.